# I have upgraded to windows 10 from windows 8.1. Can i create a recovery drive from the option in control panel?

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive

The service executive recommended to buy a recovery DVD from them for $15-$20 and use it to recovery my laptop. I mean, what is the difference?

Comment: You don't need to purchase anything to install Windows 10.  You can download a Windows .ISO for free from Microsoft.  That is the only purpose of the "recovery drive".

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon what you described, it sounds like creating a Windows 10 recovery drive will suit your needs.  There is an option to include the system files:

> 1. Open the `Control Panel` utilizing the icons view.
> 2. Select the `Recovery` icon.
> 3. Select the `Create a recovery drive` link. (if you receive a UAC prompt, select `Yes`)
> 4. Check the `Back up system files to the recovery drive` box and click `Next`
> 5. Select the USB drive you want to make a recovery drive and click `Next`
> 6. When you are ready, click on `Create`.
> 7. When the process is complete, click on `Finish`.
> 8. Remove the USB drive accordingly.

([Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4200-recovery-drive-create-windows-10-a.html))